# My view keeps moving up when tapping my textField or using the keyboard using NS notification

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uistackview, nsnotifications

I have a stack view with some texField's and a button inside, this is used for a login page

I also have a button at the bottom of the view this is used to present another view controller, this button works fine

I've set up a tapGesture recogniser that if you tap anywhere on the view the keyboard should dismiss and the view go back to its original constraints this also works fine

I've set up NS notification and in my function keyboardWillShow, when I tap in a textField the view moves up as I want it to

My problem is the moment i tap another textField or i start typing the view moves up again I'm not sure why this is

It looks like for some reason the function  gets called every time I tap on a different text field or I use the keyboard I can't see why this is happening
Any help would be appreciated because I'm new to switch

```
    view.addSubview(alreadyHaveAccountButton)
    alreadyHaveAccountButton.anchor(top: nil, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 5, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 60)



    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [emailTextfield,passwordTextfield,fullNameTextfield,signUpButton])
    stack.axis = .vertical
    stack.spacing = 20
    stack.distribution = .fillEqually

    view.addSubview(stack)
    stack.anchor(top: nil, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: alreadyHaveAccountButton.topAnchor, right:
        view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 50, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 0)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIWindow.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: UIWindow.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)


@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    let notification = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardFrame = notification?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    let keyboardFrameSize = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue

    view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardFrameSize.height
}


@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    let notification = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardFrame = notification?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    let keyboardFrameSize = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue

    view.frame.origin.y += keyboardFrameSize.height

}
```

Comment: It’s because you just keep saying `view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardFrameSize.height` again and again. So you keep moving the view up and up. You are completely failing to think about where the keyboard is and where you are (that is, where the text field is).

Comment: yes i understand what you mean but how do i make sure it doesn't move up again when i tap into another textfield, i can't see how its getting called again because the keyBoard has already shown

Comment: If you looked at some numbers it wouldn’t matter how many times you were called, because you wouldn’t move up if you were already up.

Comment: As for why it is called again, maybe that’s because you tap on a text field and your tap gesture recognizer dismisses the keyboard and the text field brings it back again.

Comment: exactly i totally agree that's what's not making sense, the view has moved up so why does it keep moving up every time i tap a textField i understand what you mean and yes your right is should not act like this